# How can I call a sliding menu at any time, any view using storyboards on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, slidingmenu, xcode-storyboard

I have gone through a lot of libraries which use a sliding menu at the first view, and then use it on every child view. But what I need to do is having it accessible at random views, which don't need to be child views from the main view. Does anyone know a library that would allow me to do that? Help would be much appreciated. (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Have you considered implementing the sliding controller from the main view then only allowing people to access it (so disable buttons/gestures for the others) for the views where you want to have a sliding controller?

Answer (score 2):

[PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController) allows you to do this.

From within your Menu view controller, simply call:

- (IBAction)openMenu:(id)sender {
  [self.revealController showViewController:self];
  }

If you store a reference to your MenuView (say in your AppDelegate), you can call this method from anywhere.